# How to compare Api response from JSON with List of IWebElements

Tags: c#, api, selenium

I am learning work with API and how to use it with selenium. I have API which returns me some values. In my example I will use "City".

By this For cycle I got all the cities from API into my List

```cs
for (int i = 0; i < filter?.Count; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Label: {filter[i].Label}");

    for (int j = 0; j < filter[i].Data?.Count; j++)
    {
        var currentData = filter[i].Data[j];

        titleList.Add(currentData.City);
        Console.WriteLine($"City: {currentData.City}");
    }
}
```

API class is more longer, but in this example it's not necessary to show everything.

```cs
public class Data
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "value_key")]
    public string City { get; set; }
}
```

Also I have got the `IList<IWebElement>` with all the cities.

So right now I have **titleList** with all the cities from API and Also I have list of all cities in `IList<IWebElement>`

My question is How I can compare these two Lists? I have read something about the Except, but it did not work for me(Maybe I did something wrong).
**My goal is to verify if the all cities from api(titleList) are also visible on the page.**

Here is another failed try:

```cs
foreach (var element in allAuctionsTitle)
{
    var isDifferent = titleList.Where(titleItem => !element.Text.Equals(titleItem, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)).Any();
    Console.WriteLine("Differencies" + isDifferent);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Except on the list should work. If all elements of titleList(api) should be present in WebElement, then you could just use *titleList.Except(webElement)*. This statement would return a enumerable with elements in titeList not in webElement.